# LMMS freeze while plugin the VST using ubuntu22.04

Tags: wine, freeze, lmms, daw, vst

I do not know why lmms will freeze after i double click the vst dll file.
I had already check my vst plugin path in Edit->Setting.
[i had put my lmmsappImage file in .wine directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GBp6.png)

[and had put my vestige plugins dll file in program file(x86) directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvnMU.png)

[when i double click any dll file here, lmms will freeze immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnNVO.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. A dll file is a Windows file and can not be run on Ubuntu.